# Show more Items

Tags: php, jquery

I am building an app which shows various locations.

I want to show 10 place at a time on click of show more button. Presently, i am able to show 10 items on first go but on second time click all the items are getting displayed whereas `i want consecutive 10 items each time i click` on show more button.

```
<?php
    echo 
    "<script>
     $('ul')
     .find('li:gt(10)')
     .hide()
     .end()
     .append(
     $('<li><a>Show More</a></li>').click(function(){
     $(this).siblings(':hidden').show().end().remove()
     }));
    </script>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have generally two options. Part of you HTML might be also helpful.

1) Search only for ten hidden elements, you are now searching always for 10 elements (so they are always the same). Provided the hidden elements are li you can do:

```
<?php
echo 
"<script>
 $('ul')
 .find('li:hidden:gt(10)')
 .hide()
 .end()
 .append(
 $('<li><a>Show More</a></li>').click(function(){
 $(this).siblings(':hidden').show().end().remove()
 }));
</script>";
?>
```

2) Store somewhere the actual number of displayed items and add 10 to it each time the button show more is clicked.

```
<?php
echo 
"<script>
 var itemsDisplayed = 10;
 $('ul')
 .find('li:gt(itemsDisplayed)')
 .hide()
 .end()
 .append(
 $('<li><a>Show More</a></li>').click(function(){
 itemsDisplayed = itemsDisplayed + 10;
 $(this).siblings(':hidden').show().end().remove()
 }));
</script>";
?>
```